# java.text.ParseException: unparsable date: "Mon, 22 Aug 2005 20:21:52 +0200"

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I got this error.

What is wrong on my code?

```
String line = "Date: Mon, 22 Aug 2005 20:21:52 +0200";
String datestring = line.substring(6);
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ");
Date inputDate = null;

try {
    inputDate = dateFormat.parse(datestring);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My errorlog:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon, 22 Aug 2005 20:21:52
>   +0200"    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)   at netspy.EMail.parseLine(EMail.java:133)   at
>   netspy.EMail.parseMail(EMail.java:91)     at
>   netspy.FileManager.findMails(FileManager.java:66)     at
>   netspy.BaseFrame.switchContent(BaseFrame.java:218)    at
>   netspy.BaseListener.actionPerformed(BaseListener.java:79)     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: this code works are you sure you posted the right one?

Comment: You could try to add use  the pattern "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ"

Comment: Yes. I added the errorlog.
Also adding the other pattern didnt fix the exception.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is your system locale something else than English? Try to explicitly specify the locale:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ",
        Locale.US);
```

Comment: nice catch, didn't even think about this. Op's code worked for me as is

Comment: The Local setting should be changeable, the date can be from different timezones.
Im actually from Germany so i tried:
`DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ", Locale.GERMANY);`

Probably still throwing an exception.

Comment: Is `Mon, 22 Aug 2005 20:21:52 +0200` a valid string for Germany? Looks like an English string to me. If it were German the string should have been `Mo, 22 Aug 2005 20:21:52 +0200`.

Comment: Thats what you meant.
I got you, that was the reason. Small thing but took me over 1 hour :-) Thanks